# IOS delete/hide table row section and cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

Ive been struggling on this for a couple of days now trying a number of different ways trying to remove sections of my table view.

**ExportSettings.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewRowAction *MovemberFeatures;
```

This is connected to the movember section.

**ExportSettings.m**

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
UITableViewCell* cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


if(cell == self.MovemberFeatures)
    return 0; //set the hidden cell's height to 0

return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Currently it is not building and am not sure why. Any help would be great[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: you want to delete particular row?

Comment: I want to delete the Movember features section

Comment: Can you post your code for all the tableview delegates you implemented?

Comment: Have you used the [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] 
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

Comment: no i havent, thats the only method :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cell == self.MovemberFeatures)
```

You are trying to compare a `UITableViewCell` with a `UITableViewRowAction`. That's where the build fail I think.

You can see in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/index.html) that `UITableViewRowAction`defines a single action to present when the user swipes horizontally in a table row. Not at all suited for what you want to do.

Use the `NSInteger` associated with the section to refer to it.

As suggested by [Bharat Modi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3882147/bharat-modi), use `[tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` to delete a section from the table.